# A question on realizable sample complexity

Tags: machine-learning, sample-size

I came across the following exercise, and I just can't seem to crack it:

> Let $l$ be some loss function such that $l \leq 1$. Let $H$ be some hypothesis class, and let $A$ be a learning algorithm. show that:
>
> $m^{\text{stat, r}}_H (\epsilon) = O\left(m^{\text{stat, r}}_H (\epsilon/2, 1/2)\cdot \log(1/\epsilon) + \frac{\log(1/\epsilon)}{\epsilon^2}\right)$

Where $m^{\text{stat, r}}_H (\epsilon)$ is the minimal number $m$ such that for any realizable distribution over training examples $D$ we have that:
$$\mathbb{E}_{S \sim D^m}\left[ l_D(A(S)) \right]\leq \epsilon$$

And where $m^{\text{stat, r}}_H (\epsilon, \delta)$ is the minimal number $m$ such that for any realizable distribution over training examples $D$ we have that:
$$P_{S \sim D^m}\left( l_D(A(S)) \geq \epsilon \right) \leq \delta$$

Thanks a lot in advance!